clamav and memory mapped files
I am using clamav on Enterprise Linux 9. In order to optimize it's scanning I am getting list of modified files using fanotify (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html).
But it states " The fanotify API does not report file accesses and modifications that may occur because of mmap(2), msync(2), and munmap(2).".
Referring to msync (mainly), it's documentation states: "msync() flushes changes made to the in-core copy of a file that was mapped into memory using mmap(2) back to the filesystem.". So my assumption is, mysnc would modify memory mapped file and that fanotify would not report such modification.
So the question is how does clamonacc which uses fanotify manages to find out and scan file changes by msync?
Thanks in advance!

Your questions do not make sense. The "memory mapping" performed by mmap() can only done while the file is open by a process (for reading and/or writing). There is no file attribute that indicates that the file is or was "memory mapped" (note the past tense). "Memory mapping" is not related at all to how or where the file is stored. Are you confusing this mention of  "memory mapping" with memory-based filesystem such as tmpfs/ramfs and/or a ramdisk?

@sawdust I think I am referring to msync (mainly). It's documentation states:  "msync() flushes changes made to the in-core copy of a file that was mapped into memory using mmap(2) back to the filesystem.". So my assumption is, mysnc would modify memory mapped file and that fanotify would not report such modification. But you are correct in that, my general tenses are wrong. I am going to edit the question.

Focusing on msync() is misguided. It's merely a timing mechanism to immediately write back dirty (i.e. modified) memory pages instead of waiting until the memory mapping is dismantled using munmap(). "So the question is ..." - Have you also read the man page for mmap(2)? There's a relevant section titled Timestamps changes for file-backed mappings.

@sawdust I think I am looking for generic solution if one exists. The section you referred to is uncertain (first paragraph) and based on options (second paragraph). I did try code from https://learningdaily.dev/reading-and-writing-files-using-memory-mapped-i-o-220fa802aa1c and commented mmio_read and added sleep(10) calls after every API call in mmio_write. I see that using fanotify I get notification after open, truncate and close but not after any mmio apis. I was wondering if there is a way to do that. Hope that clarifies.

I expect that there is no solution by monitoring files accesses. You need to be aware that there are several layers of functionality to access/modify files. The read() and write() syscalls from userspace use the VFS layer. fanotify presumably has hooks in this top software layer so that it (software) can monitor file accesses. But memory-mapped file access will bypass this top-level VFS layer that fanotify relies on. Note that mmio uses virtual memory which relies on special hardware (the MMU) with some kernel support.
